# Retreiving a Receipints Email Address in Win32Com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I'm using win32com with Python to get some stuff done with Outlook. While I manage to get the email address of a particular emails' sender, I'm not able to do this with the recipient.

I was only able to get the recpients name by doing this:

```
print(msg.to)
```

If I do this:

```
print(msg.recipients)
```

I get this:

```
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

I do get the senders address with the following code:

```
print(msg.SenderEmailAddress)
```

but this won't work with "to" or "recipients".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. Use `Recipients (index)`, where index is the name or index number, to return a single Recipient object. The name can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The [Recipient.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property returns a string representing the email address of the `Recipient`.

The [Recipient.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property returns or sets a Long representing the type of recipient. Can be one of the [OlMailRecipientType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype) enumeration.

```
recipients = message.Recipients

for recipient in recipients_list:
    #Now that the for loop has gone into the Recipient Collection, this should print the recipient name
    print(recipient)
    #This is the "Address", but for me they all appeared as Exchange Users, rather than explicit email addresses (SMTP)
    print(recipient.Address)
    #I used this code to get the actual addresses (SMTP)
    print(recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must loop through each recipient  in the `msg.recipients` collection and print teh recipient.Address property:

```
for recip in msg.recipients:
  print(recip.Address)
```